# Why time.strptime does not to convert date

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code that checks certificate expiration date.

```
import ssl
import OpenSSL
import time
def get_SSL_Expiry_Date(host, port):
cert = ssl.get_server_certificate((host, 443))
x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert)
raw_date = x509.get_notAfter()
print (raw_date)
#print(x509.get_notAfter())
dexpires = time.strptime(raw_date, "b'%Y%m%d%H%M%Sz")
# print (dexpires)
get_SSL_Expiry_Date("google.com", 443)
```

---

The code works when this line is commented:

```
dexpires = time.strptime(raw_date, "b'%Y%m%d%H%M%Sz")
```

I get this error:

```
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the `datetime` module instead of `time`?

Comment: Make sure your comments are also on the same indent block. we can't see it in the question but that's what probably happened.